# Missing vmlinuz and initrd.img in 13.04

Tags: dual-boot, 13.04

I am attempting to set up a new MacBook Pro as dual boot OSX Mountain Lion/Ubuntu 13.04, using rEFInd as the boot manager, and the most recent 64-bit Mac image from [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/).

According to all the tutorials I have been able to find, I need to copy over the vmlinuz and initrd files to a place that rEFInd can see them in order to actaully boot into Ubuntu after installing it.

However, these files do not appear to exist in my install, as the following are broken links:

```
/vmlinuz -> /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic
/initrd.img -> /boot initrd.img-3.8.0-19-generic
```

Where can I find/download these files? Or has something changed between the 13.04 daily builds that I can find tutorials for and the actual release version?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 13.04 released with Linux 3.8.0-19 but it's now on 3.8.0-21, could that be the problem here? They should be in the /boot directory.

When installing Ubuntu with the standard options, /boot is a directory on the root partition. Some have a separate partition for the boot directory, this is then mounted on / on start-up and is specified in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to mounting a different partition!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that those files do not appear when running Ubuntu from the USB. I had to finish the install:

```
ubiquity -b
```

and then mount the appropriate partition to find them:

```
sudo fdisk -l  
sudo mount -t auto -v /dev/sda4 /mnt/sda4  
ls /mnt/sda4/boot/{vmlinux..., initrd...}
```

Comment: what does the `-b` flag do? I couldn't find a mention in the man page